# How to ignore untracked files

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
META-INF/
classes/
repository/
sample-2.0.9-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar
temp/
test-classes/
```

the above are untracked files and i want jar file and ignore other file.

basically i am doing is trying to push jar files from jenkins to bitbucket.

and i facing issue is when i do changes in that particular pom file and push again i am facing this issue. although i tried adding .gitignore file but i am unable to over come this problem.

It will be helpful if you help me with this error

and the jenkins file code looks like:

```
stage('bitbucket deploy') {

        steps {

          script{

             GIT_CREDS = credentials('bitbucket-server-cred')

            sh '''  
                echo "${WORKSPACE}"
                cd ${WORKSPACE}/target        
                git init
                git config --global user.name "admin"
                git status
                git remote add origin http://***:*****@**:***:**:***:7990/scm/or/lla-esb-artifactory.git
                git remote -v
                git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
                git add -f *.jar
                git status
                git commit -a -m "push into bitbucket"
                git push origin master

           '''
          }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the step of *actually creating* the JAR file. [`Untracked files are not staged or committed`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), and it will *not* be pushed into the git repo. When you perform the `git pull`, it pulls the master branch from your remote. But since you are not tracking the JAR file, it means that it is not being uploaded to git to begin with.

The ideal thing to do here would be to build the JAR file after pulling the repo using `mvn package` or whatever action you have in your POM to build the JAR file. Remember to clean your workspace when the build stage is complete.

Alternatively, since it seems that all you are doing in this build step is including the JAR file in the repo, you can run `git add *.jar` to add the JAR file to the repo where you have it as an untracked file, and remove this build step, since the file will be in the repo to begin with.

Comment: Thank you so much @tripathiakshit for the reply... this is the step to build a jar and i am clearing workspace too                                         
         stage('package') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }